# Actionscript class property data validation with annotation

Tags: actionscript-3, validation

asp.net mvc has something that allows for class property validation using annotation.

is there a similar thing in actionscript?

Answer (score 0):

Believe this might be what you're looking for: http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/metadata_3.html#159728 if not you can also create custom annotations in Flex though I've yet to delve into this myself.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread, but this sounds like exactly what you're looking for. http://www.graniteds.org/confluence/display/DOC/8.+Bean+Validation+(JSR-303)